# HTML text does not re-appear with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use the following code to display and then fade out some text:

```
$('#submit_new_player_order').click(function(e){
//some data to define data_to_send      
$.post(ajaxurl, data_to_send, function() {
    alert('it is in here');
    $('#fade_in_text_sort').html('Your sort order is being saved!');
})
.done(function() {
    alert('done');
    $('#fade_in_text_sort').html('We saved your data!').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
})
});
```

This works fine the first time I click the submit button and it displays the text correctly. When I click on the submit again I get both alerts but the text is never displayed again. Since I'm using fadeout I figured it would display it again but it doesn't do that. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time ajax is done you hide (fadeOut) the element, so next time you need to show it (before you hide it again):

```
$('#fade_in_text_sort').html('We saved your data!').show(0).delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
```

Here is an example with a button:

```js
$('#submit_new_player_order').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#fade_in_text_sort').html('We saved your data!').show(0).delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fade_in_text_sort"></p>
<button id="submit_new_player_order">Submit new order</button>
```